# Is it possible to store 'html' code in another page like a stylesheet?

Tags: html, css

just wondering if there was like a stylesheet for 'html'. What if I have a second 'html' file which contains a lot of the same 'html' as the first one. Instead of copying and pasting all the different bit can I use something like a stylesheet to store and make that 'html' appear on the second page?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file

Answer (score 1):

**PHP METHOD:** Just rename your html file from `fileName.html` to `fileName.php` so you can use `php include` for templating your site.

Here's an example of keeping the same navbar, say `navbar.php` on all pages:

**navbar.php:**

```
<ul>
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
  <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

The above will be added to every page including the file.

**INDEX.PHP:**

```
<div class="nav">
    <?php include("pathTofile/navbar.php"); ?>
</div>

<div class="banner">
    ....
</div>
```

**ABOUT.PHP:**

```
<div class="nav">
    <?php include("pathTofile/navbar.php"); ?>
</div>

<div class="someDiv">
    ....
</div>
```

**CONTACT.PHP:**

```
<div class="nav">
    <?php include("pathTofile/navbar.php"); ?>
</div>

<div class="someDiv">
    ....
</div>
```

So if you need to make some edit to your navbar, you can just edit the `navbar.php` file and the changes will be reflected on all pages.

Comment: but but ..the OP hasn't added a `php` tag

Comment: @Reddy Agreed. But this method is the cleanest method to achieve what he want. But if he sees this and states that he doesn't want to use PHP, then I will delete this :) Cheers

Comment: this will limit the idea to only Php users. I think using jquery you can just say `$('div').load()`. it would be acceptable by wide crowd.

Comment: @Reddy Googling it now. Will incorporate it to the answer too. Thanks for the heads up bro.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible using HTML alone but many server-side and client-side frameworks like PHP, Node.js, and Django allow you to insert one HTML file into another for example using the same header across a website.

Or you could use JavaScript to import the file. Here is an example using the jQuery library:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      $("#header").load("header.html");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```